# Grunt + Babel successfully runs but doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs, grunt-babel

I'm rather new to grunt/npm but after reading up the docs. I have made myself a `package.json` and a `Gruntfile.js`. Here's my folder structure:

```
/
|- src
    |- myfile.es6
    |- anotherfile.es6
    |- etc.
|- Gruntfile.js
|- package.json
```

---

### What I have

Here's my `Gruntfile`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        babel: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                plugins: ['es2015']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'src/',
                    src: ['*.es6'],
                    dest: 'dist/',
                    ext: '.js'
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['babel'])
};
```

And then here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Cheddar",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-babel": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt --verbose"
  }
}
```

#### What does it do?

I have my `src/` folder which contains my source files (`*.es6`). I want to transpile these to a `dist/` directory with grunt.

### What I've tried

Then I installed all the dependencies / babel-cli / grunt-cli/ etc. with `npm install` and `npm-update --save`

Seems good, so I went ahead and ran grunt:

```
$ grunt
Running "babel:dist" (babel) task

Done.
$ ls
Gruntfile.js  node_modules/  package.json  src/
```

The `ls` is outputting the exact same thing as before I ran `grunt`. So nothing is appearing to happen. Where's my output `dist`? This has been bugging me for the past few hours. I've tried installing `babelify`, and quite a few other fixes from blogs across the internet but alas, nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the keyword "presets" instead of "plugins":

```
babel: {
  options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      presets: ['es2015']
  }
  ...
}
```

When I use your configuration, grunt seems to error out because it can't find the ***plugin*** called "es2015". Everything worked after I made that change.

Comment: Also, you can add that to a .babelrc file:

    {
        "presets": ["es2015"]
    }

Then you don't have to worry about it in the Gruntfile config at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try a more literal example from the README like:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    babel: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            presets: ['es2015']
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                'dist/myfile.js': 'src/myfile.es6'
            }
        }
    } });
```

After you get that working try specifying `*.es6` etc. under files.  If you look at the source for the grunt-babel plugin it may be more limited than one would assume.

You can also just use `npm scripts` and specify the babel command line directly which I feel is simpler than using grunt.